# Iterate plot creation over columns of dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, plot, time-series

I have a dataframe consisting of 30 time series of opening stock prices taken from the Dow Jones index:

```
source=pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dow_Jones_Industrial_Average')
df = pd.DataFrame(source[1])
tickers_symbols=df['Symbol'].values.tolist()
dataset = pd.DataFrame()
for t in tickers_symbols:
    tmp = yf.download(t, period='5y', progress=False)
    tmp.reset_index(inplace=True)
    tmp['Ticker'] = t
    dataset = dataset.append(tmp, ignore_index=True)
dataset=dataset.drop(["Close", "High", "Low", "Adj Close", "Volume"], axis=1)
dataset = dataset.pivot_table(index="Date", columns="Ticker", values="Open")
```

What I want to do is use the function below to retrieve four diagnostic plots for each stock and save them in a specific folder.

```
import statsmodels.tsa.api as smt
def tsplot2(y, title, lags=None, figsize=(12,8)):
        fig= plt.figure(figsize=figsize)
        layout=(2,2)
        ts_ax=plt.subplot2grid(layout, (0,0))
        hist_ax=plt.subplot2grid(layout, (0,1))
        acf_ax=plt.subplot2grid(layout, (1,0))
        pacf_ax=plt.subplot2grid(layout, (1,1))

        y.plot(ax=ts_ax)
        ts_ax.set_title(title, fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')
        y.plot(ax=hist_ax, kind='hist', bins=25)
        hist_ax.set_title('Histogram')
        smt.graphics.plot_acf(y, lags=lags, ax=acf_ax)
        smt.graphics.plot_pacf(y, lags=lags, ax=pacf_ax)
        sns.despine()
        plt.tight_layout()
        return ts_ax, acf_ax, pacf_ax
```

The way I tried is the following:

```
for column in dataset:
    tsplot2(dataset[column], title=dataset[column], lags=50)
    plt.savefig(f"{figures}/"+column+"Plots.png", format="png")
```

However, when I run the code I get the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I am not sure what this means in this context. Is there a way to fix this loop?

Comment: As noted, `title=column` instead of `title=dataset[column]`, which is a typo / not reproducible. So I'm voting to close the answer for that reason. Do not post answers to problems caused by typo type issues, they should be called out in comments and flagged, as there is a specific close flag **Not reproducible or was caused by a typo**. These questions are typically downvoted, closed and deleted, as they are of no benefit to the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a mistake in the function call:

```
tsplot2(dataset[column], title=dataset[column], lags=50)
```

should be

```
tsplot2(dataset[column], title=column, lags=50)
```